# I want to show data on recyclerview android from firebase realtime database.. but i am unable to load dynamic data into adapter array

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to show data in a recyclerview in android. The data will be retrieved from a Firebase realtime database, but I'm facing a weird issue.

To get the desired data from the database, I want to read the database twice, at two different nodes.

I have attached my code below, along with visual overviews of the data structure.

The RecyclerView only shows the demo value, which is hard-coded into the adapter array. It is not showing the edata that should be added from inside the for loop.

Please note: My adapter and helper are all correct.

I've attached my code below:

`

```
package com.example.attendx;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView featuredrecycler;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    ArrayList<FeaturedHelper> admin_cls = new ArrayList<FeaturedHelper>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        //Hooks Recycler view
        featuredrecycler = findViewById(R.id.featured_recycler);
        DatabaseReference Root_Ref, UserProfile_Ref;
        Root_Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        UserProfile_Ref = Root_Ref.child("userprofile").child(uid);

        DatabaseReference User_Sir_ji_Ref;
        User_Sir_ji_Ref = UserProfile_Ref.child("Sir_ji");

        //method created for recycler view
        featuredrecycler(User_Sir_ji_Ref, Root_Ref);

    }

    private void featuredrecycler(DatabaseReference user_Sir_ji_Ref, DatabaseReference root_Ref) {

        featuredrecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        featuredrecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(dashboard.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));


        //ArrayList<FeaturedHelper> admin_cls = new ArrayList<>();

        admin_cls.add(new FeaturedHelper(R.drawable.icon, "test0", "test2")); // This DEMO SHOWS


        user_Sir_ji_Ref = user_Sir_ji_Ref;
        user_Sir_ji_Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    DatabaseReference ClassHeader;
                    ClassHeader = root_Ref.child("classroom_header");
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){

                        Log.d("SNAPSHOT", snapshot1.getValue().toString());

                        ClassHeader.child(snapshot1.getValue().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                String Cls_name, createdBy;
                                Cls_name = snapshot.child("ClassName").getValue().toString();
                                createdBy = snapshot.child("TeacherName").getValue().toString();

                                admin_cls.add(new FeaturedHelper(R.drawable.icon, Cls_name, createdBy)); // THIS DOESNOT SHOWS

                                Log.d("SNAPSHOT", Cls_name+"\n"+createdBy);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recycler View Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UNABLE_TO_READ_SIR_JI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        Log.d("SNAPSHOT", admin_cls.toString()); // HERE IT SHOWS ONLY ONE ELEMENT 
        adapter = new FeaturedAdapter(admin_cls);
        featuredrecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

`

Please help me to solve this weird issue.

The database structure is shown in the links below:

[userprofile node has sir_ji node inside, which has class_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZUyk.jpg)

[class_header node has node of class_id, which contains class details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyx28.jpg)

Comment: can you share your json database?

Comment: yeah sure just a moment.. but i would like to mention that using log i have verified that i am getting the desired value in Cls_name and createdBy variables inside for loop

Comment: So what is the exact data you want to get, in which order? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the data in `admin_cls`, you need to tell the adapter about that fact so that it knows to rerender the views.

You do this by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever you make changes (or are done making changes) to the data in `admin_cls`.

```
user_Sir_ji_Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            DatabaseReference ClassHeader;
            ClassHeader = root_Ref.child("classroom_header");
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                ClassHeader.child(snapshot1.getValue().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String Cls_name, createdBy;
                        Cls_name = snapshot.child("ClassName").getValue().toString();
                        createdBy = snapshot.child("TeacherName").getValue().toString();

                        admin_cls.add(new FeaturedHelper(R.drawable.icon, Cls_name, createdBy));

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //  Add this
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase works as async, you are suppose to put the code inside the method `onDataChange`. Since you are using `for loop` with connection Firebase inside it, maybe you can create a delay for it while retrieving the value.

```
for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
   Log.d("SNAPSHOT", snapshot1.getValue().toString());
   //Here your all codes...
}
//Here you call the this function.
//1000 = 1 second
CreateDelay(1000, () -> {
   Log.d("SNAPSHOT", admin_cls.toString());
   adapter = new FeaturedAdapter(admin_cls);
   featuredrecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
});
```

Method `CreateDelay` and its interface

```
public static void CreateDelay(final long delayMillis, @NonNull final DelayCallback delayCallback) {
    final Looper l = Looper.myLooper();
    if (l != null) {
        new Handler(l).postDelayed(delayCallback::onFinished, delayMillis);
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface DelayCallback {
    void onFinished();
}
```

Comment: thanks but all code means creating array inside that or jst adding value to array like earlier??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question @MillenniumChowdhury

Comment: if you see my previous code i have added values to array inside the ondatachange...but have set adapter outside the on data change  adapter = new FeaturedAdapter(admin_cls);
   featuredrecycler.setAdapter(adapter); now what shouid i do define array inside ondatachanged along with setting the adapter too

Comment: @MillenniumChowdhury yes, you can try my answer, define it inside the `onDataChange`